# Caption only in table of content, not shown in the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, fullpage

I have a set of full-page images. I want these images to be shown in the table of contents, but, since they are full page, I do not want any caption to be shown around them in my text.

My code is approximatelly like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{memoir}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}  %%%%%
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{subcaption} %%%%
\usepackage{changepage} %%%%
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\cleartorecto
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\mainmatter

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)}]
\node[anchor=south west] (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{MyFigure}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\caption*[{Sometext to be shown in the list of figures}]{ }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now, I know that if my image is fullpage, I would not see the caption below. Nevertheless, is there a way to properly omit the caption and let it appear only in the table of contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caption package you are using offers

```
\captionlistentry[figure]
  {Sometext to be shown in the list of figures}
```